# Convert date column in excel to date string in Laravel Excel

Tags: php, laravel, maatwebsite-excel, laravel-excel

I'm using `maatwebsite/excel 3.1`. In my excel file with extension `.xlsx`, I have about 5 columns and I don't know what value user will insert, it can be string, number, or date.

When user insert date, after I read file, that date value will be an integer. Here is the code I read file:

```
$excelData = Excel::toArray(new CampaignImport(), $file);
```

My date value in excel `25-07-21` will become `44402`

I know that there is a way convert that integer to date by:

```
\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date::excelToDateTimeObject($excelData['date-column']);
```

But problem is I don't know which column user will insert date, so I trying to check all 5 columns in my excel file, if it is an date integer, I will call that function to convert it to date string. But I don't know how to check an integer if it is a date type in excel.

Can you give me a solution for this?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I declare using this before put in models:

```
$date = intval($row['date_column']);
```

then enter the above variable with a format like this:

```
'date_column' => \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date::excelToDateTimeObject($date)->format('Y-m-d');
```

[the attempt was almost successful but for the year it became random as shown below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8A53.png)